# NASM assembler data error

Tags: nasm

After:`section .data`, the line reads:`number db 7 dup 0`. The error message is:`Comma expected after operand 1`. But, there is no operand. Why the error message?

Comment: It would help if you posted a code sample.

Answer (score 2):

NASM does not use `dup` as MASM does, instead it uses `TIMES`

```
number          times 7 db 0
```

Section 3.2.5 from the manual:
[3.2.5 TIMES: Repeating Instructions or Data](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html)